# How to convert Expression<Func<T1, bool>> to Expression<Func<T2, bool>>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have a need to convert the expression

From:  `Expression<Func<T1, bool>>`

To: `Expression<Func<T2, bool>>`

Since `T1` and `T2` can be different, I understand there will be a need to re-create the expression. I am hoping for a small method which I can reuse for multiple objects.

Comment: It is very clear what OP is asking. I am voting to re-open this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in the general case. Here is a quick example to illustrate my point:

```
class Apple {
    public int Weight {get;set;}
}
class Orange {
    public int Diameter {get;set;}
}
Expression<Func<Apple,bool>> heavy = a => a.Weight > 250;
```

Even if you traverse the expression tree of `heavy`, you would not be able to convert `Weight` of the `Apple` to anything related to an `Orange`.

Calling methods that apply only to `Apple` inside the expression would present similar problems.

In a limited case when the expression on `T1` is limited only to members available on `T2`, you would be able to make a conversion using [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Override [`VisitMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.visitmember(v=vs.110).aspx), check `MemberExpression node`'s content for `T1`, find a corresponding member in `T2`, and construct the replacement `Expression`. This may be a viable trick for querying backend DB using expressions constructed on DTOs.